What-brick-is-this type of question
We already have one of the what-brick-is-it kind of question and I suspect, from other LEGO communities, that we are going to get many, many more. The problem I see is that the title is useless. What do you think if we establish that the brick should be described in the question? Would that help? would that be useless?

I agree, and am curious myself the different methods to identify a brick. I've create a potential "canonical" question to help facilitate this idea.

We should also decide on a common tag - so far I've seen [part-id] [piece-id] [piece-name] [piece-information] all in use.

Where the submitter does not know what set it is from, perhaps we should encourage something along the lines of:
what brick is this - summary description (eg 4x2x8 with holes and a window)
That would at least help us get an overview from the title. We'd need to have a standard nomenclature described in the FAQ though (question on this here). 

Agreed. It is practically imperative that if we plan to field these, that they have clear and distinguishable titles. The current "what brick is this" title is horrendous and the last thing the site needs, among other things, is a collection of identically titled questions all talking about different bricks. One could be descriptive on its functionality versus detailed about its stud count and dimensions, as long as whichever is done, it's identifiable.
